# Excel VBA select range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able by double clicking on a cell to move to a certain location in the same workbook, in the example below, I want to select the cells in Column B:BR of the current row.
For this I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("o7:o7")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
       Worksheets("INCOMING").Activate
       Range("r" & ActiveCell.Row & ":br" & ActiveCell.Row).Select  
    End If  
End Sub
```

but it keeps on giving me the "run-time error '1004' select method of range class failed.

There is always an entire row selected.
anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So, do you want to trigger the event executing double click on cell "O7"? Or not... Then, do you want selecting a range in a different worksheet, from B to BR, on the 7th row?

Comment: Yes, if i double click on O7 i would like to activate worksheet "incoming" and select the cells R:BR of the active row in the worksheet "incoming"

Comment: ... and what do you want to do with the cells you have selected? You do know there's a lot you can do with Excel without selecting the cells first :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code event. It assumes that `ActiveCell` from your code should be the one initially double clicked ("O7"):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.address = "$O$7" Then
        Cancel = True
        With Worksheets("INCOMING")
            .Activate
            .Range("B" & Target.Row & ":BR" & Target.Row).Select
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Double clicking on cell "O7", the seventh row of "INCOMING" sheet is selected between "B" and "BR" columns...

If you want selecting the row of the `ActiveCell` of "INCOMING" sheet, you need to change `Target.Row` with `ActiveCell.Row`.